# Calling a method in a loop

Tags: xquery

I have the following method

```
declare private function local:get-range($count as xs:integer, $skip as xs:integer, $start as xs:integer, $end as xs:integer) as xs:integer*
{
  let $newStart := $end + 1
  let $newEnd := $end + $skip

  let $endCorrection := if ($newEnd > $count) then ($newEnd = $count) else ()

  return ($newStart, $newEnd)
};
```

It takes a few integer parameters and returns an array of two integers.

Here's how I use it

```
let $start := 0
let $end := 0
for $iteration in (1 to 7)
let $startEnd := local:get-range(7, 1, $start, $end)
let $start := $startEnd[1]
let $end := $startEnd[2]
return $start
```

I loop 7 times passing in $start and $end and in the loop I update start and end to be the values returned from the method call.  I expect $start to be 1 in after the first call, 2 after the second and so forth.  But it comes out as 1 every time.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to calculate and then we could help you formulate a solution in XQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As functional programming language, XQuery's variables are immutable, think of them as constants that get hidden if redefined for the current scope.

Loops in XQuery are only used to work on all members of a sequence, not to repeatedly apply operations to a (repeatedly changed) value.

Use **recursion** if you want to do this kind of loops instead.